# Linux command line tool validating XSD 1.1?

Tags: command-line, command-line-interface, xml-validation, xsd-1.1

Is there any command line tool that validates XML against a XSD version **1.1**?

[Xmllint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libxml2) does not validate version 1.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XSD 1.1 is currently supported by Saxon and by Xerces J.  Both should run without trouble under Linux.

Comment: It seems to say here that Xerces J only supports XML 1.0 ? http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/

Comment: The page you point to is about Xerces J 1.4.4, released in 2001.  The [release notes](http://diglib.hab.de/wdb.php?dir=drucke/6-3-quod-2f) suggest that support for XSD 1.1 was first added experimentally in release 2.7.0 of Xerces J (current release appears to be 2.11.0).

Comment: Also don't confuse XML 1.0 with XSD 1.0

Answer (score 5):

I found a handy wrapper around Xerces-J: https://www.dropbox.com/s/939jv39ihnluem0/xsd11-validator.jar

```
java -jar xsd11-validator.jar -sf my.xsd -if my.xml
```

You can update the Xerces-J lib by unzipping the jar, dropping the new Xerces-J in it, then rezipping it to a jar

[Reference](https://jeszysblog.wordpress.com/2012/09/27/free-and-open-source-xsd-1-1-validation-tool/)

Edit: Updated download link

Comment: Since Sep 30, 2018, the source code for the jar is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/jeszy75/xsd11-validator). You can build the jar yourself using Maven (`mvn package`).

Answer (score 0):

xmllint unfortunately could not support XML Schema 1.1 but alternatively it supports RelaxNG based Schema (including all the advancements similar to the XML Schema 1.1).

Following is the procedure could be used to overcome xmllint limitations:

1. implement your validation XML Schema version 1.1 based on Oxygen Editor reverse generator (based on already existing XML files). 
   [it could be downloaded from here with the 1 month license free](https://www.oxygenxml.com/xml_editor/download_oxygenxml_editor.html)
2. resulting XSD 1.1 file will not be accepted by xmllint with the following error messages:

   ```
   xmllint --schema user.xsd --noout user.xml 
   user.xsd:565: element element: Schemas parser error : Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}element': Invalid value for maxOccurs (must be 0 or 1).
   user.xsd:741: element element: Schemas parser error : Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}element': Invalid value for maxOccurs (must be 0 or 1).
   WXS schema user.xsd failed to compile
   ```

   however the xml schema could be converted into relaxng schema with the help of [RNGConv](http://java.net/downloads/msv/nightly/rngconv.20060319.zip) tool which is a part of the Kohsuke Kawaguchi's MSV project by 
   applying following conversion command:

   ```
   java -jar rngconv-20060319/rngconv.jar user.xsd > user.rng
   ```
3. resulting relaxng schema file could be used with the xmllint:

   ```
   xmllint --relaxng user.rng --noout user.xml 
   user.xml validates
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I answered this question [over here at AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/1120727/51957).
It includes working links to the  Xerces-J wrapper `xsd11-validator.jar` and a comfortable bash script for easy usage.