# Elements in random order and maxOccurs > 1

Tags: python, xml, xsd

I need to create a **XSD** 1.0 that validates a **XML** file.

The validation will use **lxml.etree** from **python**, and this tool is supporting just XML Schema 1.0 ([lxml with schema 1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559263/lxml-with-schema-1-1))

The structure that I need to use is of type:

```
    item
    | owners*
    | config+
    | | config_id
    | | tests*
    | | picked?
    | | capability*
    | | | name
    | | | value
```

Used notation are:

- `*` The element can occur zero or more times.
- `+` The element can occur one or more times.
- `?` The element is optional.

Elements in config tag can be in any order, this means that I can't use `<sequence>` indicator.  `<all>` indicator is giving me the random order, but in this case the `maxOccurs` is 1. `<choice>` indicator with `maxOccurs="unbounded"` will give me the random order and the multiple number of elements, but there will be no bottom limit for elements.

My XSD file looks something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>

<!--Schema version: 1.0, date: 29-02-2016-->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <!-- definition of complex types -->    
  <xs:complexType name="capability_type">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="value" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="config_type">
    <xs:all>
      <xs:element name="config_id" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="tests" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" 
                          maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      <xs:element name="picked" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="capability" type="capability_type" 
                          minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:all>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="item_type">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="owners" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" 
                          maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      <xs:element name="config" type="config_type" minOccurs="1" 
                          maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <!-- definition of schema -->
  <xs:element name="item" type="item_type" />

</xs:schema>
```

Using this schema I receive error:

> element element: Schemas parser error : Element
>   '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}element': Invalid value for
>   maxOccurs (must be 0 or 1).

Is there any alternatives for my problem ?

Comment: Alternative approach: when making schemas I almost always use a schema generator, which I feed in my proposed final XML. I use a simple tool I wrote in .NET but they are also floating around online, like here: https://xml.mherman.org  ... The output absolutely must be reviewed carefully. Also those online tools are sometimes total garbage.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are alternatives:

1. Completely abandon the random order requirement.  It tends to be more trouble than it's worth.
2. Partially abandon the random order requirement by migrating `config_id` and `picked` outside of the `xs:all` and migrating `maxOccurs="unbounded"` from the children of `xs:all` to `xs:all` itself.
3. Keep the random order requirement, migrate `maxOccurs="unbounded"` to `xs:all`, and use XSD 1.1 assertions to enforce the other occurrence constraints.

Comment: Do you know any XSD 1.1 validator in linux that is also free?

Comment: See [Linux command line tool validating XSD 1.1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18782706/linux-command-line-tool-validating-xsd-1-1)